# DBSCAN vs Kernel Density Estimation

Tags: density-estimation

What is the difference between DBSCAN and Kernel Density Estimation

Comment: Can these algortihms actually be compared at all? They try to provide answers to different problems: clustering versus probability density estimation.

Comment: Is DBSCAN not estimating density? Though it is used for clustering

Answer (score 0):

[DBSCAN algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dbscan-clustering-in-ml-density-based-clustering/) – density-based spatial clustering of applications with noise. This algorithm uses a density-based notion of the cluster and the key idea is that for each point of a cluster the neighborhood of a given radius has to contain at least a minimum number of points.

[Kernel Density Estimation](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/02664763.2016.1277191#_i4)

Kernel density estimation is a really useful statistical tool with an intimidating name. Often shortened to KDE, it’s a technique that lets you create a smooth curve given a set of data.

This can be useful if you want to visualize just the “shape” of some data, as a kind of continuous replacement for the discrete histogram. It can also be used to generate points that look like they came from a certain dataset - this behavior can power simple simulations, where simulated objects are modeled off of real data.

[Applications of kernel density estimation](https://bookdown.org/egarpor/NP-UC3M/kde-ii-app.html)

Comment: From your answer, I understood that DBSCAN is used for clustering with some threshold of minpts,radius. whereas KDE is for estimating the distribution of data (shape of data). Is this correct

Comment: AFAIK, Yes it is!!